# UIButton and selected highlight state

Tags: ios, ios5, uibutton

The UIButton has a normal/default, highlighted, and selected image. I then have a `IBAction` method that is called on `Touch Down`. The method changes the highlighted image depending if it's selected. But when the button is selected, the method is called and so the highlight image is changed, however what is displayed is the normal/default image with a tint. I have tested that image used is in not `nil`. What happens is when the UIButton in a selected state is pressed displays the normal state with a tint. Why is it not using the highlight image and is there another way of showing a selected highlight image?

Comment: I think the following url can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907166/uibutton-highlighted-state-not-showing-when-clicking-over-a-selected-uibutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this problem by using the selected state and notifications (not via the UI). When a notification is called I change image for the default state, change the selected state and then change the image for selected state.

**Update**: 
I came up with a much better idea from another question that was doing something similar to me. The way to do it is to things in `setSelected`

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if ( selected )
    {
        [self setImage:[CFCHStyleSheet imageForTickButtonChecked] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setImage:[CFCHStyleSheet imageForTickButtonChecked] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [self setImage:[CFCHStyleSheet imageForTickButtonCheckedDisabled] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setImage:[CFCHStyleSheet imageForTickButtonUnchecked] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setImage:[CFCHStyleSheet imageForTickButtonUnchecked] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [self setImage:[CFCHStyleSheet imageForTickButtonUncheckedDisabled] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }

    [super setSelected:selected];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you set the highlighted state in the IBAction method? You only need to set the highlighted image for you button when you create it. It will switch automatically. Adding a tint when selected is the default behavior of 'selection' when no highlighted image is assigned.

if your using Interface Builder, just assign the highlighted image there.

Im assuming your looking for normal button selection behavior with your IBAction method set to the `touchUpInside` event.

Comment: I have rewritten my question.

Comment: try calling the method that changes the highlighted state with a short delay using `self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method and see if that helps.